# Cannot replace the double space in the array Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Here is what I tried and what I am trying to achieve:

```
>>> d = [[0.4246955,0.42829293,0.43621248,0.42680067],
... [0.42453277,0.42806646,0.43601942,0.42658913],
... [0.42681128,0.43040696,0.43824464,0.42888936],
... [0.42648485,0.4299298,0.43789476,0.42854127],
... [0.42436373,0.4276249,0.43576592,0.4263624]]
>>> d
[[0.4246955, 0.42829293, 0.43621248, 0.42680067], [0.42453277, 0.42806646, 0.43601942, 0.42658913], [0.42681128, 0.43040696, 0.43824464, 0.42888936], [0.42648485, 0.4299298, 0.43789476, 0.42854127], [0.42436373, 0.4276249, 0.43576592, 0.4263624]]
>>> print(d)
[[0.4246955, 0.42829293, 0.43621248, 0.42680067], [0.42453277, 0.42806646, 0.43601942, 0.42658913], [0.42681128, 0.43040696, 0.43824464, 0.42888936], [0.42648485, 0.4299298, 0.43789476, 0.42854127], [0.42436373, 0.4276249, 0.43576592, 0.4263624]]
>>> s = ""
>>> for i in d:
...     s = s+str(i).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",","").strip()+"\n"
...
>>> s
'0.4246955 0.42829293 0.43621248 0.42680067\n0.42453277 0.42806646 0.43601942 0.42658913\n0.42681128 0.43040696 0.43824464 0.42888936\n0.42648485 0.4299298 0.43789476 0.42854127\n0.42436373 0.4276249 0.43576592 0.4263624\n'
>>> print(s)
0.4246955 0.42829293 0.43621248 0.42680067
0.42453277 0.42806646 0.43601942 0.42658913
0.42681128 0.43040696 0.43824464 0.42888936
0.42648485 0.4299298 0.43789476 0.42854127
0.42436373 0.4276249 0.43576592 0.4263624

>>> s = s.replace("  ","0 ")
>>> print(s)
0.4246955 0.42829293 0.43621248 0.42680067
0.42453277 0.42806646 0.43601942 0.42658913
0.42681128 0.43040696 0.43824464 0.42888936
0.42648485 0.4299298 0.43789476 0.42854127
0.42436373 0.4276249 0.43576592 0.4263624
```

As one can see that the each element is not of the same length. Hence, while converting to string I am getting double spaces, which disturbing my splitting process in another program.
I wanted to know how I can replace the double spaces with single space or with 0 and space as I tried in the above code.
For example see the following:
The string is:

```
0.4246955 0.42829293 0.43621248 0.42680067
0.42453277 0.42806646 0.43601942 0.42658913
0.42681128 0.43040696 0.43824464 0.42888936
0.42648485 0.4299298 0.43789476 0.42854127
0.42436373 0.4276249 0.43576592 0.4263624
```

, so I want it to become like this:

```
0.42469550 0.42829293 0.43621248 0.42680067
0.42453277 0.42806646 0.43601942 0.42658913
0.42681128 0.43040696 0.43824464 0.42888936
0.42648485 0.4299298 0.43789476 0.428541270
0.42436373 0.4276249 0.43576592 0.426362400
```

Please let me know what I can do.

Comment: I don't see any double spaces in `s` before you do the replace.

Comment: There's no double spaces, why do you think it doesn't line up where a 0 is omitted?

Comment: actually, it won't be seen in here, but when I am catching it a string on client side, I get to see 2 spaces. I just want to eradicate it with 0 appended in the last of the values where there are less values.. Is it doable?

Comment: Why convert the list of list of floats to string? Why not just flatten and then join?

Comment: You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten the input list, and then [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to print each number with the precision that you desire.

Comment: I am sending the data through Socket to another program and there I am catching the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to accomplish something like this:

```
>>> result = "\n".join([" ".join([format(n, "0.08f") for n in line]) for line in d])
>>> print(result)
0.42469550 0.42829293 0.43621248 0.42680067
0.42453277 0.42806646 0.43601942 0.42658913
0.42681128 0.43040696 0.43824464 0.42888936
0.42648485 0.42992980 0.43789476 0.42854127
0.42436373 0.42762490 0.43576592 0.42636240
```

Change the format string ("0.08f") to suit your needs.

Comment: Let me try it sir. I guess this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a simple formatting `.8f`

```
>>> d = [[0.4246955, 0.42829293, 0.43621248, 0.42680067], [0.42453277, 0.42806646, 0.43601942, 0.42658913], [0.42681128, 0.43040696, 0.43824464, 0.42888936], [0.42648485, 0.4299298, 0.43789476, 0.42854127], [0.42436373, 0.4276249, 0.43576592, 0.4263624]]
>>> dFormatted = '\n'.join(' '.join(f'{num:.8f}' for num in nums) for nums in d)
>>> print(dFormatted)
0.42469550 0.42829293 0.43621248 0.42680067
0.42453277 0.42806646 0.43601942 0.42658913
0.42681128 0.43040696 0.43824464 0.42888936
0.42648485 0.42992980 0.43789476 0.42854127
0.42436373 0.42762490 0.43576592 0.42636240
>>>
```

Comment: f strings ([PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) are nice and even more concise than the `format` function or the `string.format` method but only available in 3.6 IINM.

Comment: @PauloScardine yes, you can do it with `'{num.8f}'.format(num=num)`, `'{.8f}'.format(num)`, `'%.8f' % num` and with `format()` like in your answer